# What's the difference between layout_gravity="center_vertical" and layout_centerVertical="true"

Tags: android, android-layout

I have such layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="@dimen/DP_3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="xxx"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="yyy"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want all children place vertically inside parent RelativeLayout, however, **layout_centerVertical="true"** did the trick, but **layout_gravity="center_vertical"** did nothing. I thought they got same meaning, but not really, did I miss understand sth?

Comment: RelativeLayout does not have layout_gravity parameter. Look at the documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html.

Comment: thanks, I was looking at the R.attr doc which didn't say anything about this and made me confused

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`layout_gravity` is the attribute for `LinearLayout`, which won't work in `RelativeLayout`.

If you change your `RelativeLayout` container to `LinearLayout`, the elements are positioned in center using `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="xxx" 
        android:padding="5dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="dsf" 
        android:padding="5dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="yyy" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Reference Links:

[android:layout_gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity)

[android:layout_centerVertical](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerVertical)

Comment: @fifth sure.. added reference links :) and mostly eclipse  also shows warning in xml design while you use wrong properties like this :)

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's easy:

```
layout_centerVertical="true"
```

did the trick... in a **RelativeLayout**

while

```
layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

works in a **LinearLayout**.

Comment: @DiieBarcia It doesn't take a genius to understand that you must apply the same to **all** the Views which have to be affected. Or does it?