# Android center DatePicker don't work

Tags: android

How can I center a DatePicker? **Layout_centerhorizontal** does not work it aligns it to the left.

Here's my code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/txtTitulo"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"

    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:paddingLeft="22dp"/>
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/DatePicker1"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
</DatePicker></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: it's ok,  thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Parent of the DatePicker is a LinearLayout. So set

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

in the DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

[`layout_centerHorizontal` is used in RelativeLayouts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerHorizontal), not LinearLayouts

Think you want [`android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity)

Comment: Thank you all, android: layout_gravity = "center" work for me

Answer (score 0):

add this to your DatePicker:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

the difference between layout_gravity and layout_centerVertical/Horizontal is explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25054311/7137584

Comment: Remember also to set layout_width="match_parent"

Answer (score 0):

To center the DatePicker I have used ConstraintLayout.

The code looks like this inside of the ConstraintLayout:

```
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dp_dueDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_priority"/>
```

Widht: wrap_content

layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf: Parent

layout_constraintRight_toRightOf: parent

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this problem just now and have managed to solve it via code. Just thought to share this if anyone else is still having problems (in Kotlin):

```
//retrieve DatePicker object
val datePicker = view.findViewById<DatePicker>(R.id.date_picker)

//go to its first child (LinearLayout), retrieve its LayoutParams object, cast to 
//FrameLayout.LayoutParams object and set the gravity to Center
datePicker[0].let { ll ->
  if(ll is LinearLayout && ll.layoutParams is FrameLayout.LayoutParams) {
    (ll.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).gravity = Gravity.CENTER
  }
}
```

OR alternatively:

```
//Create a generic function to center DatePicker object
fun DatePicker?.center() {
  if(this != null) {
    this.getChildAt(0)?.let { ll ->
      if(ll is LinearLayout && ll.layoutParams is FrameLayout.LayoutParams) {
         (ll.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).gravity = Gravity.CENTER
      }
    }
  }
}

//And to use:
val dp = view.findViewById<DatePicker>(R.id.date_picker)
dp.center()
```